# Got banned sitewide from a website and I can't figure out how it recognizes me

Tags: ip

I have an ipv6 address, I changed it many times and cleared cookies and flash cookies but that didn't work. The first part of the IP address stays the same whenever I change it, not sure if that's relevant. How does the website recognize me despite me doing everything mentioned above?

Comment: Did you try disabling IPv4 completely?

Comment: Another victim of the BanHammer....

Comment: Likely the absolute best way to get around the block is to contact the site administrators or moderators, explain your regret for whatever action got you banned and ***constructively*** agree a course of action. Circumvention of a ban of this type in the ways you are attempting shows little remorse and does not encourage anyone to stay their hand from the banhammer when they find you again.

Answer (score 1):

It is checking your Public IP not your local computer's IP. The public IP is assigned to your entire network by your ISP. This address may or may not be changed on a regular basis, depending on how they assign addresses.

Comment: I am a moderator on several discussion forums, it is not uncommon when we have "troublesome" posters to block not just a single IP address, but entire ranges that are assigned to the same carrier/ISP or company, so this answer is completely plausible and quite likely.

Comment: @acejavelin How do I change my IP address enough so that it doesn't recognize it?

Comment: @Xasatel You likely can't, only your ISP can... they control what IP address is publicly seen when you use the Internet. Best to just wait out the ban, or if you feel it is unjust then appeal it, most websites have a way of doing that.

Comment: @acejavelin Can I ask my ISP to change it? Will getting another modem help?

Comment: @Xasatel You can always ask, but depending on they network they may not be able to accommodate your request, or just refuse to even if they can. Getting another modem could change your public IP, depending on how your ISP's network is configured, or it could stay exactly the same. You could try TOR or other privacy VPN solution, it will mask your IP public IP address, although some sites block those in general.

Comment: @Xasatel Even if you get connected, you will likely see your account locked  out as well... Moderators rarely just block IP's without making sure other things like account username and email address are blocked as well.